# How to customize form validation errors in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a file in codeIgniter in which I could just edit so that I can customize the form validation messages?

[image]

I just want to place them in a bulleted list to consume less space.

Here's the code that I'm using to output the error messages:

```
<div class="alert <?php echo $alert['alert_type']; ?> min-form">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
        <h4><?php echo $alert['main_message']; ?></h4> 
        <?php echo $alert['sub_message']; ?>
</div>
```

Basically the `$alert['sub_message']` is just getting its data from `validation_errors()` function from CodeIgniter which outputs the validation errors from a form.

Comment: If not already, I'd suggest a client-side validation layer as well, so the CodeIgniter layer is only seen if they somehow still are able to submit the form.

Comment: Also, I'd consult the CI docs: [Callbacks: Your own Validation Functions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks).

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks I already have client side validation using liveValidation http://livevalidation.com/

Comment: Have you seen the docs about custom validation?

Comment: yeah I found it. Just edit the $_error_prefix and $_error_suffix from  Form_validation.php in the system/libraries folder.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used CI, but I believe you need to be adding or editing a language file.

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu editing system files is not recommended. You can create files with the `MY_` prefix to ensure your custom code is not lost when upgrading your system files, and it makes it easier for other devs to find out what you've customised.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can extend the form_validation class for maximum control by creating `application/libraries/MY_form_validation.php` to add extra validation rules - I've attached an example below.

**It is bad practice to edit system libraries directly**; CI provides better options (*overrides/customization thru `MY_` classes, [libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html), [hooks](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html), etc*). This gives you the benefit of easily upgrading CI versions & keeps your application portable / custom code isolated from the core framework.

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * CodeIgniter Form Validation Extension
 */
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    /**
     *  MY_Form_validation::valid_url
     * @abstract Ensures a string is a valid URL
     */
    function valid_url($url) {
        if(preg_match("/^http(|s):\/{2}(.*)\.([a-z]){2,}(|\/)(.*)$/i", $url)) {
            if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) return TRUE;
        }
        $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('valid_url', 'The %s must be a valid URL.');
        return FALSE;
    }

    /**
     * MY_Form_validation::alpha_extra()
     * @abstract Alpha-numeric with periods, underscores, spaces and dashes
     */
    function alpha_extra($str) {
        $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('alpha_extra', 'The %s may only contain alpha-numeric characters, spaces, periods, underscores & dashes.');
        return ( ! preg_match("/^([\.\s-a-z0-9_-])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }

    /**
     * MY_Form_validation::numeric_comma()
     * @abstract Numeric and commas characters
     */
    function numeric_comma($str) {
        $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('numeric_comma', 'The %s may only contain numeric & comma characters.');
        return ( ! preg_match("/^(\d+,)*\d+$/", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }

    /**
     * MY_Form_validation::matches_pattern()
     * @abstract Ensures a string matches a basic pattern
     */
    function matches_pattern($str, $pattern) {
        if (preg_match('/^' . $pattern . '$/', $str)) return TRUE;
        $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('matches_pattern', 'The %s field does not match the required pattern.');
        return FALSE;
    }   

}

/* End of file MY_form_validation.php */
/* Location: ./{APPLICATION}/libraries/MY_form_validation.php */
```

Answer (score 11):

You can change the **Error Delimiters** in this way:

```
<ul>
<?php echo validation_errors('<li>', '</li>'); ?>
</ul>
```

docs: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#changing-the-error-delimiters

For v3: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#changing-the-error-delimiters

Answer (score 3):

You can use
`<?php echo form_error('field name', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>`
for displaying errors individually.

[Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#errordelimiters)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the delimiters from `<div>` to `<li>` by using CodeIgniter's `set_error_delimiters` function:

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<li>', '</li>');
```

You should do this immediately after loading the Form Validation class.

This will change the way `validation_errors()` **and** `form_error('field_name')` are displayed. So you will need to add `ul` or `ol` as follows:

```
echo '<ul>' . validation_errors() . '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1):

The same as answers above, just if you want with bootstrap:

```
<ul>
<?php echo validation_errors('<li><span class="label label-danger">', '</span></li>'); ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

**3 Ways to format/ customize error display**

**1. Changing delimiters Globally:** To globally change the error delimiters, in your controller method, just after loading the Form Validation class. Load after the form_validation library load. you can load in the constructor as well.

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
```

**2.Changing delimiters Individually:** Each of the two error generating functions shown in this tutorial can be supplied their own delimiters as follows

```
<?php echo form_error('field name', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
OR
<?php echo validation_errors('<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
```

**3. Set delimiters in a config file:** You can add your error delimiters in application/config/form_validation.php as follow. Set this 2 config variable in the file. `$config['error_prefix'] ='<div class="error_prefix">';` and `$config['error_suffix'] = '</div>';`

Ref Link: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#changing-the-error-delimiters

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `system/language/english/form_validation_lang.php`

I believe you can either edit it, or copy it to `application/language/english/form_validation_lang.php`

Comment: We can have a copy of the same file to `application/language/english/form_validation_lang.php` (Applicatoin's Language folder) and do any customization we want

Answer (score -8):

In order to validate devexpress controls in the page using javascript, use the following code:

```
ASPxClientEdit.ValidateGroup(null);
```

or

```
ASPxClientEdit.ValidateGroup('validationgroup');
```