# Codeigniter - Changing the Error Delimiters - Putting all Errors in one div tag, not individual

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to set up the Error Delimiters and it works great. However, there is one problem. The messages come up for all the errors at the top, which is great, but I want all of the problems to be like this:

```
<div> 
Username field too long
Password doesn't match
Please accept the terms
 </div
```

Not like this:

```
<div>Username field too long</div>
<div>Password doesn't match</div>
<div>Please accept the terms</div
```

Screenshot:

**Not like this**
http://gyazo.com/566c6752de463957fb39b103738d30cf

**But like this** 
http://gyazo.com/47b284c5376a2ec94c560a697d3a1572

My current code in my view file  (without all the other junk):

```
 <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

My code for the controller:

```
public function user() {

       $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|min_length[5]|max_length[25]|is_unique[users.username]|xss_clean');

 //more rules but removed them just for the quesiton

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters(' <div class="alert alert-danger"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>', '</div>');

        $this->index();

    }


}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This could help, maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271558/how-to-customize-form-validation-errors-in-codeigniter

Comment: @nevermind Christian Giupponi's answer there was almost exactly what I was going to suggest, so I would assume it would help OP here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the error delimiters you set in the controller and go to your view file, and replace `<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>` with

```
<?php if (validation_errors()){
    echo ' <div class="alert alert-danger"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button><b>You\'ve made some errors! Please check them below: <br></b>' ;
    echo validation_errors();
    echo '</div>';                                 
}
?>
```

Problem solved!

Comment: No need to use an `if` statement. Just move the HTML to the first and second parameters of `validation_errors()`. Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11272294/811240).